# Create a textfile from Winform and write and read from the textfile

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I'm completely new to Windows Form Application. I'm using C# scripting for winform. How do I dynamically create a textfile from inside the script and write strings to that textfile? Can I also read from that same created textfile the data that I just stored? Thanks

Comment: It is the same as for all other targets (console, WPF). If you have problem adopting your existing code to WinForms - please show exact code that causes you issues with migration. Note that UWP is slightly different, but most concepts are the same too.

Comment: You should first learn how to ask question in Stack Overflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a basic code to create files and write text into it.
You will need to add `using System.IO;` at the top of your project to use it and you may need to edit it to make it work with your buttons

```
if (!File.Exists("FILENAME.txt")) // If file does not exists
{
    File.Create("FILENAME.txt").Close(); // Create file
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("FILENAME.txt"))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("WRITE SOME TEXT"); // Write text to .txt file
    }
}
else // If file already exists
{
    // File.WriteAllText("FILENAME.txt", String.Empty); // Clear file
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("FILENAME.txt"))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("WRITE SOME TEXT"); // Write text to .txt file
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. i learned about how to create and read from files in python, c++ and java but in c# it kind of got confusing. so this helps a lot. thanks